# Javascript css bottom empty block problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

My webpage has one empty container. Why? Where is the problem i can't find. I will share my codes and screenshots. Can you help me please?
note: If i make big ( i mean full screen ) to screen, then this empty block has gone. But if i do small screen for example 50% of the screen, then it will appear.

First, let's look screenshots:
Full screen screenshot:

[image]

When half of the screen it appear like this:

[image]

Loginpage.css codes:

```
.login-page {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6083b1b7, #5970f19f, #6083b1b7);
}

.navbar-light {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
}

.login-page-hr {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.192);
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.login-page-slogan {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.login-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.google {
    background-color: #4285f4;
    color: white;
}
```

Footer.css codes here:

```
a {
    color: inherit;
}

.item1 {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #6bd1f0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}

.item1:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #48976a;
}

.item1:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.item2 {
    background: rgba(49, 49, 54, 0.993);
    color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    margin: 1px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #292a30;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item3:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.item4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #25252b;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item4:hover {
    background-color: #4267b2;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.item5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #202025;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item5:hover {
    background-color: #da0e0e;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.footer-container {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 54, 0.993);
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 6fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

here empty small block problem with position fixed and bottom 0:
[image]

Comment: looks like something managed by the slideshow component you're using?

Comment: i just used sidebar in homepage, not login page

Comment: i use this slider: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-slider

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: im  using react.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

The problem is from `.footer-container`, If I see the screenshot you listed correctly, so this is a footer, and footer must be fixed to be on the bottom of the screen, that is why there is additional unnecessary space on the bottom of the screen.

### Solution

To fix this issue, try adding `position: fixed;` & `bottom: 0;` to your `.footer-container`.

### Minimal example:

Here is a minimal example to show that `position: fixed;` & `bottom: 0;` will fix this issue:

```css
.footer-container {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 54, 0.993);
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 6fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-container">
</div>
```

And here is the complete solution to your question:

```css
a {
    color: inherit;
}

.item1 {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #6bd1f0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}

.item1:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #48976a;
}

.item1:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.item2 {
    background: rgba(49, 49, 54, 0.993);
    color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    margin: 1px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #292a30;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item3:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.item4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #25252b;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item4:hover {
    background-color: #4267b2;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.item5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #202025;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item5:hover {
    background-color: #da0e0e;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.footer-container {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 54, 0.993);
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 6fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but now it gives a small empty block. I have added the screen shot end of the post (look above)

Comment: @efesahin You mean those white space?

Comment: and also i can't see google button when i do full screen because of white space bug

Comment: @efesahin Well, those space are from the same reason. Their is must be fixed size for them to get them to bottom.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: @efesahin Try setting `position: fixed;` & `bottom: 0;` on the container that above the footer.

Comment: on the all of the body page container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235077/discussion-between-kevin-m-mansour-and-efesahin).

Comment: i tried for the body page (login-page css) but it doesnt work

Comment: i changed the bootstrap codes, and i solved